# Rotate image in opencv depending on skew angle...!

Tags: android, opencv

Need help.. consider following two links
 [1=> Finding Skew Angle](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-detect-skew-angle/)

[2=> Rotate image according to Skew Angle](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/10/opencv-rotation-deskewing/)

I wants to do the same, and the code given on this links works good. But the problem is, See the text displayed in these images, this code works fine for ***well aligned text only*** (as displayed in the images on the given links), ***but It gets failed when your text is in scattered form***. Please tell me how to do it for images that contains text in the scattered form..? Thanks in advance..!! [ Here the main challenge is TO FIND CORRECT SKEW ANGLE..]

Comment: Can you give an example image the code fails on?

Comment: No, because I am new to StackOverflow, and yet I don't have rights to upload the image..!

Comment: try to find some way to post a link to an image then and someone else can include it in your question for you

Comment: @user1926512 Have you get any success?

Comment: @Harpreet Not yet..! If you know the answer then, please let me know..

Comment: Please provide an example image that fails, also include the code you have written so far in your question. This will help us to identify the problem.